# Failed Windows 10 updates when dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows-10, updates

I'm using Windows 10 on a Dell computer Inspiron 3000 series dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04.

Each time I agree to update it when I start it back it tells me its returning to the last known good version.

How can I get it to update successfully?

Comment: The problem you're having with Windows updates has nothing to do with dual booting with Ubuntu. I suggest you download the latest Windows version, use the official tool to make a bootable USB stick, boot from it and follow instructions to update Windows.

Comment: Here's some official MS steps for making the bootable USB stick 
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO